# Where are .jigdo files for Ubuntu amd64?

Tags: jigdo

After searching on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ for `.jigdo` files (in order to build up-to-date images with low cost of resources because I have an apt proxy configured) I noticed that there're only files for arm, arm64, ppc, s390x, etc, but not for amd64 and i386. Where to get them from for the currently supported Ubuntu or Ubuntu LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ for amd64 and i386 instead of http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/.